# How to Store mplleaflet Object?

Tags: python

I'm new to mplleaflet. The map created by this code mplleaflet.display(fig) seems to be transient. I can't save it as .png to my local drive or show it as Jupyter Notebook output on my GitHub repo (the result window is blank!). How can I 'capture' it as a permanent image without manually snipping it?